# A 10-letter word puzzle - what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I am a **ten letter** word.

> The first four letters has power to rule.
>
> Next four letter can be eaten.
>
> Last three letter represents a lady.
>
> I can fly as well.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> a [kingfisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingfisher)

The first four letters has power to rule

> king - a male monarch

Next four letter can be eaten.

> fish - gill-bearing aquatic craniate animals that lack limbs with digits; often, but not always, edible

Last three letter represents a lady.

> her - objective form of the feminine pronoun in English

I can fly as well.

> a kingfisher is a bird, and not a flightless one

Comment: Exact Answer......